# Display a message (popup) when line item added to netsuite sales order

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a workflow that displays a popup when certain items are added as line items on a sales order.

If I'm understanding correctly, it appears you can't create workflows this way.

So my questions:
1. Am I right?
2. If not, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: What kind of pop-up do you want? Some are easier that others. I don't think you can accomplish this with a workflow though

Comment: I just need to remind the salesperson to ask the customer a question if they add one of a few items to the order.

Answer (score 2):

Line items cannot be accessed through workflows, instead we can build a client script to validate.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a client script to check each item as it's entered, and if it matches your criteria, you can trigger a simple javascript alert()